# is it possible not to include the folder inside the WEB-INF in url in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have project using spring mvc, and sort all the views in different folder under the WEB-INF folder. in order for me to access the view, I need to define in url the specific folder like this. http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/FolderUnderWEB-INF/thejspfile 
for example http://localhost:8080/StationControl/includes/SuccessTemp
but I already define in my servlet this

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/includes/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My problem is that I don't want to show the include folder in URL, how will I do that? I,m stack with this problem, thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files and folders above WEB-INF directory can be accessible. For example, the URL to `index-1.jsp` would be `http://localhost:8080/test-web/index-1.jsp` in the web browser. You could place `index-1.jsp` in a folder above the WEB-INF directory and your page should be accessible through web browser. Also, check to confirm paths do not conflict with Spring request mappings in configuration and web descriptor files.

In your `spring-mvc.xml`, or whatever name you had, should include the MVC annotation and resource mapping as defined below.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/SuccessTemp/**" location="<path to folder>" cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

You could fetch files through web browser. The URL would be `http://localhost:8080/StationControl/SuccessTemp/<path to file>`.

### UPDATE Screenshot

[image]

From screenshot, the URL to jQuery would be `http://localhost:8080/test-web/scripts/jquery/jquery-3.0.0.js` in web browser.

Comment: @jsmweb : Thank you for the response, yeah I get that, but if I put the jsp file outside the WEB-INF then it would become accessible to user. and what Im trying to achieve here is that I want to put in my web browser url is http://localhost:8080/StationControl/SuccessTemp  and not this  http://localhost:8080/StationControl/includes/SuccessTemp, is that possible?

Comment: You could do that. Your project name should be `StationControl`, a sub-folder `SuccessTemp` in webapp directory, and the url will be `http://localhost:8080/StationControl/SuccessTemp/<path to the file>`. Please update us with your result.

Comment: when I try this localhost:8080/StationControl/SuccessTemp in my browser the requested resource is not available, but when I put the folder,  localhost:8080/StationControl/includes/SuccessTemp, its fine. but I dont want this. my subfolder is includes and the SuccessTemp is the jsp file.
hehe Im stack with this problem spending almost two day searching and finding a way to solve this. LOL and until now I can't find a way.

Comment: in my web.xml I already define the url patter, like this

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StationControl-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/includes/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: I've updated my answer to your question. I would suggest using `<mvc:resources/>` and `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your jsp files directly in /WEB-INF/includes/
and configure prefix value as /WEB-INF/includes/
and suffix value as .jsp
and your controller's request mapping is set as only "/SuccessTemp" from where you are calling jsp files
then it will not add include folder name in your URL.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/SuccessTemp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String callSuccessTemp() {

        return "SuccessTemp";
    }
```

also configure resource handler as below

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Yes I already did this. thanks, but still the same problem. page not found.. :)